# Angular JS getting something in dropdown menu from api

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am getting this json data from an api:

```
$scope.industry = [];

    $http.get('/industrygroup?languageid=1')
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.industry = result.data;
        });
```

the json data is $scope.industry

and I use ng-option to get a values for my dropdown menu:

```
ng-options="p.Name for p in industry[0].Occupations"
```

and that works fine, I am just looking to change this to use Name instead of Occupation. Here is my JSON below to show you:

```
{
      "Language":{
         "Id":1,
         "Name":"English"
      },
      "Occupations":[

      ],
      "Id":2,
      "Name":"Food and Beverage"
   }
```

I am looking to get the Name "Food and Beverage" in my dropdown. This was example of 1 row that was returned from my api, so I am looking to get all Names (Not Language Name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get all the names from the result.data.  Something like this using underscore:

```
var names = _.uniq(_.pluck(result.data, 'Name')));
$scope.names = names;
```

This may also be what you need:

```
p.Name for p in industry
```

Comment: what do I put in my ng-options?